# How sound waves travel for reverse parking sensors?

Tags: sensor, ultrasound, distance

Looking at (ultrasonic) reverse parking sensors, they're all installed with a (plastic?) cover like this:

[image]

Traditional ultrasonic sensors are installed with a mesh:
[image]

Since plastic reflects sound waves, how do reverse parking sensors work?

Comment: They are probably constructed with the plastic you see making direct contact with the sensing element or through an intermediary of comparable acoustic impedance to both.  They do not work as well as the unsealed sensors, but they are far better than the basically unworkable idea of having a signal in air encounter a sealing membrane added to your HC-SR04 and then have to transition back to air to cross a gap before reaching a sensing element inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sensors are not covered with plastics case, they are potted in epoxy resin. The resin conducts sound waves better than the air, so there is no problem about that. Similar case is installing the echosounder on boats, you can bore the hull and install the sensor to be directly exposed to water, or glue the sensor directly in the inner part of the hull. There will be a slight attenuation compared to the direct water mount, but it still work good. In a car where the medium is the air, potting the sensor into epoxy has no influence, since the air is a way worse sound conductor.